# Variable names created in a loop?

Tags: c++, stl

I was wondering if its possible to create variable names which are linked to my class in a loop using the stringstream?

For example i have this:

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
   std::stringstream button;
   button << "Button" << i;
   CreateButton button();

   button.function_name();
}
```

When i tried it I could not access the function for that class.

The function is not available... so I'm wondering if I am just overwriting the string stream. If i am is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Looks like you need an array (`std::vector`).

Comment: @billz its created in the for loop ( i should mention, the `button.function_name();` is also in the loop. I'll make that more clear in my question hold on.)

Comment: You can't reuse a variable name. Change `std::stringstream button` to `std::stringstream ss`. Also, your stream and your button both go out of scope when the loop exits.

Comment: But then i would be re-using `ss` ?

Comment: @Dave - No you wouldn't. The `CreateButton button` line stays as is.

Comment: But that only gives me one button setup - im trying to create 5 buttons all linked to the class so they have their own data. using stringstream was to use a unique name.

Comment: You seem to have run time and compile time a bit confused. You can't create compiler variables by running code ... you need a vector (as mentioned in some of the answers) or some other data structure that can hold multiple values.

Comment: @Jim yup - its first time i've come accross vectors so I'm look up about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an array or vector of buttons.

```
#include <vector> //must include this

std::vector<CreateButton> buttons(6);

for(int i= 0; i<6; i++)
{
   button[i].function_name();
}
```

Here you can think of `button[0]` as one variable, and `button[1]` as another variable, `button[2]` as yet another variable, and so on. In this way, you have six variables.

Comment: Ah excellent thats what i was looking to do :D Glad some one understood - it was hard to explain!

Answer (score 3):

Enhance your code a bit, is this what you are trying to do?

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<CreateButton> buttons;

// create buttons
for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss<< "Button" << i;
   buttons.emplace_back(CreateButton(ss.str()));
}

// use buttons
for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
  buttons[i].function_name();
};
```

Comment: No? I'm not parsing data through - i plan to but im trying to create a unique name for the class on each loop so i have button1 button2 button3, all linked to the same class, then they are all setup and available to use in my script.

Comment: @Dave, `std::vector<CreateButton> buttons(5);` For `button1`, use `button[0]`. For `button2`, use `button[1]`. Add onto the vector as you wish.

Comment: @chris yeh i understand now - i think a few people misunderstood what i was getting at!

Comment: we are trying to understand you with code :)

Comment: my attempt at it was poor i agree :P

Comment: @billz: Your *"create buttons"* code doesn't really create button, i.e your vector is empty!

Comment: sorry, just updated, `buttons.push_back(button); `

Comment: @billz: there is still a problem. Your *"create buttons"* code doesn't make sense. What does `ss` do there? Why not write `std::vector<CreateButton> buttons(6);` instead?

Comment: You are creating 6 same buttons. I just create it dynamically.

Comment: There is a flaw in this idea i've just realised... because the scope of button[i] not be set in class's header right so i can't use it in the class functions =/

Comment: @billz: The line `buttons.emplace_back(CreateButton(ss.str()))` doesn't make much sense to me. I think you wanted to write `buttons.emplace_back(ss.str())`.

Comment: it pushes a CreateButton object to the back of vector

Comment: @billz: What is `push_back` for then?

Comment: @Nawaz a bit better than push_back ?http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: @billz: `emplace_back` is not necessarily better than `push_back`. And, `buttons.emplace_back(CreateButton(ss.str()))` is overkill (and for some cases, it may not even work). You could just write `buttons.emplace_back(ss.str())`.

Comment: @Nawaz that's just guessing Dave's idea. it's not very clear what he wants to store. we guess he wants to store a button with generated string name etc. :)